# Al Añadir página nueva a sitio asp precompilado no carga master page que indico

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Estoy trabajando en un sitio **web asp** pre compilado le añado una página nueva al sitio y le asigno la propiedad `masterpagefile` dentro del `Tag`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Bootstrap/Report.master" %>
```

en el sitio existen varios máster yo quiero que use `report.master` 
el cual tiene un:

```
<.asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitle" runat="server"><./asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
y llamo desde la nueva pagina
<.asp:Content ID="TitleContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitle" Runat="Server">
    <jcmc:titlebar ID="TitleBar" Title="Agent Management: Edit Agent" Icon="user" runat="server" />
<./asp:Content>
```

pero a la hora de correr el sitio me da error, según entiendo a la hora de llamar la pagina nueva esta intentando llamar otro `master page` llamado `home.master` en vez del `report.master` que es el que deseo utilice, como es un sitio pre compilado imagino que esta intentando por defecto que utilice el máster del home he intentado utilice otro máster incluso por código **`c#`** en el evento `preinit` pero tampoco funciono, adjunto foto del error que muestra la pagina.

Gracias de antemano.

[image: error]

Comment: Hola estimado, por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y especifica el error junto con alguna evidencia de lo ocurrido para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Ok gracias lo haré

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [mcve]. Tu pregunta no queda del todo clara. Si crees que puedes agregar más información, puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias es mi primera vez posteando en el sitio

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mi Sitio web asp precompilado no permite cargar master page](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318375/mi-sitio-web-asp-precompilado-no-permite-cargar-master-page)