# Mi Sitio web asp precompilado no permite cargar master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando en un sitio web precompilado asp.net, sucede que intento agregar  nueva pagina y no reconoce la página maestra indicada, no importa como lo defina siempre intenta cargar el home.master y existen varios master y que se utilizan perfectamente en diferentes partes del sitio.
He intentado usando los eventos `OnPreInit();` e igual me sige dando el mismo error, y al no reconocer la master que le indico no encuentra los content que se encuentran en el master,
de esta forma indico el master a utilizar
`<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Bootstrap/Report.master" %>`

pero siempre intenta leer `<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Bootstrap/Home.master" %>`

alguien me sugirio que descompilara el sitio, agregara la nueva pagina y lo volviera a compilar, pero lo que estuve leyendo con las erramientas reflector o ilspy leen las dll independientes no acomodan las clases segun donde vayan, por tanto obvie esa solucion

Este es el Report.Master que deseo q llame, contiene el pageTitle que dice el error que no encuentra, cuando digo que use el home.master y quito el content pageTitle no da error o sea que la pagina corre pero no con el html que deseo que llame desde el report.master sino desde el home.master

Se que el report.master esta bien porque se usa en otras paginas ya existentes en el sitio, el problema es a la hora de annadir una pagina nueva

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Master_Bootstrap_Report" CodeBehind="Report.master.cs" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Crl" TagName="Botones" Src="~/Controls/Bootstrap/MenuButton.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Crl" TagName="Header" Src="~/Controls/Bootstrap/Header.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script> codigo javascript</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <title>Nombre Sitio</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/images/favicon.png" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/App_Themes/Bootstrap/js/menuspand.js?V=123"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintData() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MovesLineSite.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/non-responsive.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body class="master-report">

    <!-- -->
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KH88FJT"
            height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <!-- -->

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header-row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="headerLinkLogo" Target="_top" NavigateUrl="~/Report/Welcome.aspx"><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="contact-box">
                        <div class="contact-info contact-info-sm">
                            <strong>Questions?</strong><br />
                            Call us toll free at <em></em>,<br />
                            or send us an email to: <a href="ccccc@ccc.com">uu@uuu.com</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="agent-links">
                        <Crl:Header ID="HeaderControl" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <Crl:Botones runat="server" ID="CrlBotones" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitle" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Toolbar" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="content-row">
        <div class="container-fluid container-report">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer-row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="copyright">
                        <p><i>All Rights Reserved <%= DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy") %> &copy;</i></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BottomScripts" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script type="text/javascript">
codigo javascript
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el codigo de la pagina nueva

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Bootstrap/Report.master" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master/Bootstrap/Report.master"%>

<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Common" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="TitleContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitle" Runat="Server">
    <jcmc:titlebar ID="TitleBar" Title="Agent Management: Edit Agent" Icon="user" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
<script language="c#" runat="server">Codigo c# donde lleno tabla</script>

<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="EditAgentValidationSummary" runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" CssClass="form-error alert alert-danger" HeaderText="" ForeColor="" />
    <div>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="systemMsg" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <asp:Table ID="dataAgents" runat="server" class="table table-striped table-hover" >
    </asp:Table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />                  

</asp:Content>
```

adjunto foto del error que devuelve [image: error]

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos Report.master por favor.

Comment: Quizá en el web.config tengas algo como "<pages masterPageFile="Home.Master">"

Comment: ya busque y nada de nada ningun tag ni nada que diga algo parecido

Comment: Estas utilizando labherramienta de publicación de Visual Studio?,Si es así activa las opciones permitir pre compilado  actualizar . Ahora si solo estas poniéndo la nueva página en el sitio precompolado trata de activar la opción de generar ensamblados por página para te genere elncompolado de la nueva. Supongo que Report.Master ya existe o es nueva? Sines nueva genera elngompilado y los pones en el directorio bin del web site.

Comment: si estoy utilizando la herramiento del VS imagino refieres a las "propiedades del sitio/Opciones para MSBuild", Permitir que este sitio precompilado se actualice si es esa si esta activado el "Permitir que el sitio precompilado se actualice" y correctamente Report.master existe y es usado satisfactoriamente desde varios reportes

Comment: Si pero la nueva página como la publicas? Ojo que la nueva página no está dentro del dll, al menos lo que entiendo.

Comment: no la estoy publicando, tengo el sitio abierto con visual estudio 2017, annado la pagina nueva al sitio precompilado y le digo q el masterpagefile sera el report.master y no m hace caso, siempre intenta llamar al home.master por tanto no m reconoce los content q estan en el report, report.master existe en el sitio y se utiliza en varios reportes y funciona perfectamente, solo en la pagina nueva es q no carga

Comment: Cuando abres la página nueva en el diseñador de Visual Studio y le pones vista diseño, aparece la nueva página con el master correcto?

Comment: Si, en la vista de disenno el llama correctamente el codigo del report.master, sin embargo cuando corro la aplicacion es que me da el error

Comment: Cuando dices corro la aplicación, te refieres a iniciarla desde el Visual Studio con IIS Express?

Comment: correcto con visual studio y iis sever

Comment: Si desde el diseñador el master es correcto tu problema es en la publicación. No es que siempre tome Home.master sino que esta tomando esta como página maestra default la primera que encuentra en el directorio. La nueva página debería complicarse haciendon refencia al codebehind porque esta página es nueva y no está dentro del DLL por lo tanto debe estar junto a su código.

Comment: correcto eso pensaba que estaba usando el home.master como pagina maestra por default, pero no le puedo agregar codebehind al tag de la nueva pagina porque m da error a la hora de compilar ya que el codebehind debe estar en una dll y no lo encuentra si se lo annado al igual q el inherits, cosas de los sitios precompilados

Comment: No necesariamente en las opciones de MSBuild puedes indicar que genere ensamblados por página.

Comment: entonces q me opcion m recomiendas que utilice, gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrías poner el fuente de la pagina nueva .aspx?

Comment: Existe también la probabilidad que la pagina la esté sacando del caché. Borra todo cache del IIS y explorador para descartar ésta posibilidad. Aveces me a ocurrido esta situación. Porque si el diseñador del VS te muestra con la master correcta, entonces, sospecho que cuando ejecuta esta agarrando una versión aantigua del cache. Puedes verlo tambien en  Herramientas de desarrollo del chrome o edge.

Comment: Limpiaste el cache del IIS?  ¿qué pasa si en el MasterPageFile le pones cualquier? ¿te sigue cargando el Home o te dice que no existe el MasterPage? Si no le pones MasterPage igual te carga el Home.Master? Si es así, lo más probable es que esta cargando de caché o de otro lado.

Comment: bueno realice las recomendaciones, limpie la cache pero bueno esa es una que hago amenudo, luego cambie el master a otro que se usa en el sitio web y error era el mismo, intenta cargar el home.master, pero cuando quito la propiedad MasterPageFile me da error a la hora de compilar ya que esto intentando llamar controles de contenido en paginas q no tienen master pages configurada

Answer (score 0):

yo mando llamarla de este modo

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="evaluacion.aspx.vb" Inherits="usuarios" %>
```

**espero te sirva de algo**

Comment: si eso es lo que normalmente he usado siempre pero en este sitio que estoy trabajando es precompilado y atributos como el codebehind o codefile hay q quitarlo para que no de error ya que esas clases estan empaquetadas en dll y no importa lo que ponga en el atributo MasterPageFile que siempre me redirecciona a la home.master cuando en realidad nececito una llamada report.master

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error se debe a que la pagina evaluacion.aspx tiene un contenedor llamado "PageTitle" que se supone deberia estar en la Master y no lo encuentra

Comment: en el tag:
``` <% Page MasterpageFile="~/report.master"%>``` estoy diciendole q valla a report pero en realidad intenta ir al home y ahi no estan los content q necesito

Comment: Publica el tag completo de la pagina a ver que otra cosa puede ser

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Bootstrap/Report.master" %> es este le quite el codebehind por ser un sitio precompilado y es una pagina nueva

Comment: tienes el tag de otra pagina que si se muestre bien?, si le pones el AutoEventWireup="false" ?

Comment: Puse el AutoEventWireUp en false y nada

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Bootstrap/Report.master" AutoEventWireup="false" %>

la master que llamo se utiliza en otros reportes sin problema